# Figma to React - how to correct generated code on example

Tags: reactjs, figma

I have generated figma projct to react code.

Now example newsletter form looks like:

[image]

code:

```
    <div className="justify-between items-center border border-[color:var(--line,#E9E9E9)] bg-white flex gap-5 mt-4 pl-4 pr-1 py-1 rounded-xl border-solid">
  <div className="text-neutral-400 text-sm leading-5 my-auto">
    Wprowadź swój email
  </div>
  <div className="justify-center items-center bg-stone-900 self-stretch flex aspect-square flex-col w-11 h-11 px-2.5 rounded-xl">
    <img
      loading="lazy"
      src="https://cdn.builder.io/api/v1/image/assets/TEMP/d02f36bb00def9075f30278c144468da73d09c1f71451f327de792a8683d03cc?apiKey=1d1bd272d92a440e9a7fa69a4db2bbbc&"
      className="aspect-square object-contain object-center w-full overflow-hidden"
      alt="Placeholder"
    />
  </div>
  
</div>
```

But this is pure code without working example input, and now Can someone show me in the above example to do the best way to act as input to keep generated style?

I can do example:

```
 <div className="justify-between items-center border border-[color:var(--line,#E9E9E9)] bg-white flex gap-5 mt-4 pl-4 pr-1 py-1 rounded-xl border-solid">
  <div className="text-neutral-400 text-sm leading-5 my-auto">
  <input
    type="email"
    placeholder="Enter your email"
    className="border border-gray-300 p-2 rounded-md focus:outline-none focus:ring focus:border-blue-300"
  />
  </div>
  <div className="justify-center items-center bg-stone-900 self-stretch flex aspect-square flex-col w-11 h-11 px-2.5 rounded-xl">
    <img
      loading="lazy"
      src="https://cdn.builder.io/api/v1/image/assets/TEMP/d02f36bb00def9075f30278c144468da73d09c1f71451f327de792a8683d03cc?apiKey=1d1bd272d92a440e9a7fa69a4db2bbbc&"
      className="aspect-square object-contain object-center w-full overflow-hidden"
      alt="Placeholder"
    />
  </div>
  
</div>
```

But now this looks like  "input in input".

[image]

Comment: We use Figma as a UI UX tool to send to the designers as a concept.  We never use the conversion tool(s).  Inevitably something goes wrong, and Figma for all of it's awesomeness will probably not be enhancing this feature since the sale to Adobe XD.  My advice is to build in Figma with the understanding you'll be "fixing" the export, or just build the concept from scratch using Figma as a "guide".

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but when I tried the thss tool from Builder, it really looks like it works great and generates 1: 1 ui

Comment: OK -- Then keep doing what you're doing..  As I said, the process is not perfect, and it most likely never will be.